# problema instalando xampp server

Tags: php, xampp

Buenas tardes estoy trabajando en un proyecto con xampp estaba con la version 3.2 que trae php 7.3.2 de 32 bits. se me actualizo el windows 10 y ahora tengo este error al iniciar xampp.

```
[Tue Oct 04 16:10:25.786616 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 12068:tid 632] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 04 16:10:25.836727 2022] [core:warn] [pid 12068:tid 632] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Tue Oct 04 16:10:25.836727 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 12068:tid 632] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

he probado reinstalando de nuevo pero exito la unica version que me funciona ahora es xampp 3.3. que trae php 7.4.3 de 64 bits, mi proyecto se conecta con informix utilizando php_pdo_informix, pero el problema es que no puede arrancar mi xampp, alguna ayuda por favor, he probado cambaindo el nombre de example.com a local host, cambiando de puertos del 443 a otro del 80 a otro etc. pero sin exito alguna ayuda porfavor asi mismo reinstalando el vs_redist 64 de vc++ pero tampoco ..

Auxilio...

Comment: si no estas usando SSL puedes deshabilitar el servicio 443/SSL de xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por su ayuda.. despeus de batallar tanto la solucion al emnos que encontre fue en el services.msc el proceso o servicio windows?update?search me ocupaba estos puertos asi que lo deshabilite y funciono por que intente de todas las maneras sin exito lo raro es que que cada ves que se actualizaba el windows ocurria este problema. utilice cports.exe y evidentemente este servicio de windows utilizaba estos puertos y lo raro que cambiaba los puestos del xampp y tampoco funcionaba casi me vuelvo loco, en fin esa fue mi solucion. es raro pero asi fue.

Answer (score 0):

si no deseas usarlo, eso se resuelve comentando el uso de puerto 443 asi:

```
#Listen 443
```

en el archivo `httpd-ssl.conf` de xamp y luego reinicia.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57235090/17161735

en versiones mas reciente puede ser:

has esto:

1. abre `httpd-ssl.conf` aqui (o donde lo tengas instalado):

   ```
   C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
   ```
2. Comente la línea y cámbiela a `localhost`

   ```
   #ServerName www.example.com:443
   ServerName localhost
   ```
3. Y, por supuesto, reinicie su Apache o maquina.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71018094/17161735